# Iphone responsive issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsiveness

I am puzzled. I created a website for a friend which you can view here [opelversnellingsbak.be](http://www.opelversnellingsbak.be/)

The problem is that when I use chrome responsive view the website looks good and responsive on all devices. 
However when I go to it with safari on an iphone. The website is not responsive anymore. 
My media query is as follows:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
```

help would be much appreciated

Comment: I couldn't find any responsive issue in Safari. Please be more descriptibe about your issue.

Comment: Inspector shows it fine, but iphone's safari doesn't. Maybe if you shared more code we can identify it. Breakpoints seems fine, are querys set at the end of the css? It could be your `jquery-migrate`, why you need it considering you are still using jquery v1.11? Also I would load modernizr first on the js files and `master.css` as last css file.

Comment: I tried on Iphone6 and it's not responsive. You can check it by remote debugging it on Safari, then inspecting the element and checking whether your media query is loaded, or maybe overriden, it may give you a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web opelversnellingsbak.be have a frame to http://cds.one, on opelversnellingsbak.be there is no responsive css. That why it no responsive.

Your website http://cds.one is responsive good on Safari and Chrome on Iphone 6s+.

Comment: you are correct. he had setup a redirect apparently I did not know about that. Thank you